# Вывод миниатюры Reusable Text Blocks

Tags: wordpress

Использую плагин Reusable Text Blocks https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/reusable-text-blocks/
Содержимое блоков я вывожу через `<?php if(function_exists('show_text_block')) { echo show_text_block('slug'); } ?>`
А как вывести миниатюру блока в коде?

Answer (score 0):

Блок - это пост кастомного типа `text-blocks`. Поэтому миниатюру можно получить таким кодом:

```
$page = get_page_by_path( 'slug', null, 'text-blocks' );
$id = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $page->ID, 'text-blocks' );
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id );
```